# AngularJS ng-disabled и $scope.$parent

Tags: angularjs, scope

Я новичок в AngularJS, но хотелось бы понять, как сделать так, чтобы при присвоении $scope.$parent.selectedUser.id значения, отработал ng-disabled. Директива ng-disabled срабатываем в данном варианте, только при клике на любую из кнопок интерфейса. Подскажите пожалуйста вариант решения. Спасибо.
P.S. 
Если смотреть значения в scope, то все отрабатывает, как нужно, значения присваивается переменной в родительском scope. Но вот реакции DOM - нет.

```
<div ng-controller='UsersSettingsController'>   

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
                 <a href="#" 
                     class="btn btn-warning" 
                     role="button"
                     ng-disabled="!selectedUser.id"
                     ng-click="!selectedUser.id || editUser('lg')">Изменить</a>               
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>ФИО</th>
                  <th>Логин</th>
                  <th>E-mail</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in usersList" data-userId="{{user._id}}" user-check>
                  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.surname+' '+user.name+' '+user.lastname}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.userLogin}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                </tr>                      
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

// Код контрорллера

```
(function(A){
    'use strict';

    A.module('Admin').controller('UsersSettingsController', 
        ['$scope', '$modal', 'UsersService', function($scope, $modal, UsersService){

        // Инициализация переменных
        $scope.selectedUser = {
            id: null
        };  
    }]);
})(this.angular);
```

// Код директивы

```
(function(A){
    'use strict';

    var linkFn;

    linkFn = function($scope, element, attrs, $compile){
        element.click(function(n){
            $scope.$parent.selectedUser.id = attrs.userid;                                      
        });

    };

    A.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName).directive('userCheck', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linkFn
        };
    }]);
})(this.angular);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос:

```
(function(A){
    'use strict';

    var linkFn;

    linkFn = function($scope, element, attrs, $compile){
        element.click(function(n){
            var parentScope = $scope.$parent;

            parentScope.$apply(function(){
                parentScope.selectedUser.id = attrs.userid;     
            });
        });

    };

    A.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName).directive('userCheck', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linkFn
        };
    }]);
})(this.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но попробуй использовать `$apply/$digest`. *DOM* не обновляется, если при изменении данных были использованы не *AngularJS* методы.

[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m41zdbWboE)